# Open links to application from Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

The thing I would like to achieve is that I have an Intranet portal which uses links
like

```
<a href=" /files/x.docx"> x.docx < /a >
```

to open an MS-Word application.

When I'm in firefox I use customize options in

> tools-> options -> application-> microsoft-word-2007: use microsoft word 2007

This does work and the link opens directly in MS-word without any question, but chrome does not have this option in settings.
In Chrome it asks "download or open this link". I need to cancel this step like "chrome download page" that open directly links.

Comment: What will you do for those of us who don't have MS Office? I use Libreoffice, someone else might use Abiword, what will you do then? Chrome _needs_ to offer to download or save the document.

Comment: thanks.i have an webpage with specified users that use ms-office.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot force which application opens the file; HTML only transmit the data, the browser is free to display it the way it wants. HTML content will be showed directly, and other documents will be forwarded usually to the default application configured on that computer.

You could though redirect to an online service like "OnlineOffice" or Google Docs with the url  of the file to open.